# Rails 5: How to load Datatable javascript in partial html view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatables, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get a datatable to load in one of my partial views, which is simply a table. The datatable is not showing up though, only the html in the "results" partial.

Scenarios is the parent scaffold that was created. Results is the table partial I am rendering in the index of Scenarios:

My question ultimately is this: does _results.html.erb have access to the sceanrios.coffee file?

project\app\views\scenarios\_results.html.erb:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Submitter</th>
    <th>Scenario Name</th>
    <th>Options</th>
    <th colspan="8"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @scenarios.each do |scenario| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.submitter %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.scenario_name %></td>
      <td><%= render 'options', scenario: scenario %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

project\app\assets\javascripts\scenarios.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $(document).ready ->
    console.log("Working!")
    $('#example').dataTable()
```

Application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Browser Errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.self-131f13015a9da63d8ed71f09b1c89ebd2fc8c81f1b2032430e06b8547d03f943.js?body=1:48
    at jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.self-131f13015a9da63d8ed71f09b1c89ebd2fc8c81f1b2032430e06b8547d03f943.js?body=1:40
    at jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.self-131f13015a9da63d8ed71f09b1c89ebd2fc8c81f1b2032430e06b8547d03f943.js?body=1:42

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scenarios.self-8ab21e2e580c359da8a7fb9d7d533ce24740a882e2519d4675b5c305690a9b97.js?body=1:3)
    at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3233)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3363)
    at Function.ready (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3583)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3618)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LL_onclickHanlderExist' of null
    at window.LL_CustomUI.LL_CustomUI.animation.LL_CustomUI.animation.addClickHandler (hostui_animation.js?rnd=0.7801729638396486:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does _results.html.erb have access to the scenarios.coffee file?

Yes, it should be. Because `scenarios.coffee` is a [*controller-specific-asset*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets) meaning it will available to all `scenarios_controller#actions` which eventually available to the respected views which are called upon by their respected actions.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification. So is my datatable coffeescript incorrect? The javascript console.log piece of code is not firing.

Comment: There are! 3 in total. Please refer to my question to see them. I will look into the errors, but i may need help still.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but there may have been multiple issues with my code:

1. made this change in scenarios.coffee:

   $.noConflict()
   jQuery(document).ready ($) ->
     $('#example').DataTable()
     return
2. Ensure that you have only one version of jquery required. Check your application.js, and your application layout head.
3. Ensure that core jquery is loaded before the datatables jquery.